# How to reduce the space between two footnotes, making them seem more like two paragraphs?

Tags: spacing, footnotes, paragraphs

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}
%\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
\usepackage[b5paper]{geometry}
\begin{document}
{\footnotesize\lipsum[3]\lipsum[3]}
text\footnote{\lipsum[3]}
text\footnote{\lipsum[3]}
\end{document}
```

If I use `setspace` package to change the line spacing, you can see that there is a big space between the two footnotes. How do I make the footnote just like the main body, as if it were like two paragraphs?

Comment: For clarity, there is another code: `\documentclass{article} \setlength{\parskip}{0pt} \usepackage{lipsum} \usepackage[b5paper]{geometry} \linespread{2} \begin{document} {\footnotesize\lipsum[3]\lipsum[3]} text\footnote{abc abc abc abc abc\par abc abc abc abc abc abc} text\footnote{abc abc abc abc abc\par abc abc abc abc abc abc} \end{document}`

Comment: You can actually edit your question and add your additional code there, so it'll be easier to read.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The space between two footnotes is stored in `\footnotesep`. Change that to zero and voilà:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}
        % setspace is irrelevant to this problem, but I didn't comment
        % it out to demonstrate that it doesn't influence the footnotes.
%\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
%\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
%\usepackage[b5paper]{geometry}

\setlength{\footnotesep}{0pt}% <---

\begin{document}
%{\footnotesize\lipsum[3]\lipsum[3]}
text\footnote{\lipsum*[3]}
text\footnote{\lipsum*[3]}
\end{document}
```

And here's the bottom part of the output:

[image: footnotes without space in between]

I changed the `\lipsum[3]` footnote paragraphs to `\lipsum*[3]` because the unstarred version adds a `\par` at the end of the paragraphs, which leads to undesired empty lines. The starred version doesn't add the `\par`. [Thanks to [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg) for explaining!]

I commented out some parts of your MWE that aren't relevant to this problem. It is neither influenced by `setspace` (which doesn't change the line spacing of footnotes) nor by the paper size. The line `\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}` does hardly anything in a standard document because its standard value is `0.0pt plus 1.0pt`, which means there might be a one point space between paragraphs if it's really necessary in order for the entire page to look good. Unless you know why you want to change this, it's recommendable to keep the standard setting.

Comment: It doesn't work because each "lipsum" paragraph is terminated by `\par`. Using `\footnote{\lipsum*[1]}` won't give the extra line.

Comment: I was expecting something along those lines, thanks for clarifying.

Comment: I forgot to say that `\footnote` adds a `\strut` at the very end of the footnote text; if it is `\lipsum[1]`, we'll have, at the end, `\par\strut` which forces an extra paragraph.